# Error creating the table query was

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I have a page I am testing http://w-o-l.ml/register.php and when the submit button is clicked this highlighted message comes up:

---

Error creating the table 
query was

```
Create Table users(
   id_user INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   name VARCHAR( 128 ) NOT NULL,
   email VARCHAR( 64 ) NOT NULL,
   phone_number VARCHAR( 16 ) NOT NULL,
   username VARCHAR( 16 ) NOT NULL,
   password VARCHAR( 32 ) NOT NULL,
   confirmcode VARCHAR(32),
   PRIMARY KEY ( id_user )
)
```

---

I do not understand why it does this as the sql database has those columns with that information. I need help, as I am new to sql. There is also a matching login page http://w-o-l.ml/login.php

Comment: please remove sql-server tags

Comment: but it has to do with sql and i figure someone looking at that tag can answer it

Comment: the phpmyadmin tag you remove was worthy because the table is on phphmyadmin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check `exists table` and add `engine=table_type` after `create table`, like this:

```
 CREATE TABLE [IF NOT EXISTS] table_name(
       column_list
 ) engine=table_type
```

Example:

```
Create Table IF NOT EXISTS users(
   id_user INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   name VARCHAR( 128 ) NOT NULL,
   email VARCHAR( 64 ) NOT NULL,
   phone_number VARCHAR( 16 ) NOT NULL,
   username VARCHAR( 16 ) NOT NULL,
   password VARCHAR( 32 ) NOT NULL,
   confirmcode VARCHAR(32),
   PRIMARY KEY ( id_user )
) engine=InnoDB
```

Answer (score 1):

You should write your query in this way...

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_name(....)
```

So it won't create any error if table already exists